# Regarding an SSD fitting a motherboard

Tags: ssd, motherboard

I have a Sabertooth Z 77 with serialnumber: 130207846100836 and version Rev 1.xx.

I'm considering buying this SSD:
KINGSTON 480GB A400 SATA3 2.5 
https://www.stratek.dk/kingston-480gb-a400-sata3-25/cat-p/c/p9508428

Its a Danish website, you can see specifications under "Specifikationer".

Will these fit? Take into account, that my motherboard is an older version (bought perhaps 5-6 years ago).

Kindest regards

PS: Which drivers should I install from Asus' website? 
https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z77/HelpDesk_Download/

Answer (score 1):

If it works with a 2.5 inch SATA HDD, it will work with a 2.5 inch SATA SSD. They have the same physical dimensions, use the same cable type (SATA), and speak the same communications protocol.

Make sure you connect the SSD to a SATA3 (6 Gbps) capable port. (According to the online PDF manual, those are the brown or gray ones.) It *will* work on any port, but if you use the black SATA2 (3 Gbps) ports, it probably won't be able to reach its full performance.

Make sure the SATA controller is set to AHCI (native) mode (as opposed to IDE (legacy) mode) for better performance.

Drivers aren't needed for the disk. They might be needed for the SATA (AHCI) controller, depending on how they compare with the OS built-in driver for the same. (e.g. for Intel controllers, supposedly IRST provides better power savings than native Windows drivers)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I have a few comments though:
How do I change it to AHCI mode?
How do I know how they compare - the Asus drivers compared to the buildt in ones?

Lastly: Well, my HDD is old as hell - I have rather little knowledge of this (hence why I ask), but how do I see if my HDD is a SATA HDD? Does it have a special kind of wire/plug (or whatever it is called)?

Again, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The manual says your motherboard has _two_ SATA controllers (one Intel IRST and one Asmedia), but they're both _probably_ set to AHCI mode for modern operating systems. Check firmware settings (BIOS setup). As for SATA vs non-SATA -- well, your motherboard's manual has a list of all internal ports and their types. (That said, compare [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SATA_Data_Cable.jpg) and [PATA](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PATA-cable.jpg).)